# Updated file strings words together

Tags: arrays, perl, file, append

My script works, except when I append the file: it bunches my words into one string like so:

```
Joe Smo45MaleSingle
```

Originally, in the text file, they are in a column.  I want the appended file to stay in a column.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my @array1 = ("Full Name:", "Age:", "Gender:", "Marital Status:");
my @array2 = read_file("empdata.txt", chomp => 1);

print "$array1[0]        $array2[0]\n";
print "$array1[1]              $array2[1]\n";
print "$array1[2]           $array2[2]\n";
print "$array1[3]   $array2[3]\n";

print "Do you want to change the age? (y or n) :";
chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
if ($answer eq "y") {
print "What is the new age? :";
chomp(my $age = <STDIN>);
$array2[1] = $age;
write_file("empdata.txt",@array2);

print "Do you want to change marital status? (y or n) :";
chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
 if ($answer eq "y") {
    print "What is the new marital status? :";
    chomp(my $status = <STDIN>);
    $array2[3] = $status;
    write_file("empdata.txt",@array2);
}  
} else { 
 print "Do you want to change marital status? (y or n) :";
 chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
 if ($answer eq "y") {
    print "What is the new marital status? :";
    chomp(my $status = <STDIN>);  
    $array2[3] = $status;
    write_file("empdata.txt",@array2);
}       
}

close || die "could not close file";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: either structure the appended file back into colum format before the script ends or have it stay in colum format when it appends.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: restructure your question and show us your Input and output and then your code.

Comment: C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Texasam\scripting\assignment14>perl perl3.pl
Full Name:        Joe Smo
Age:              45
Gender:           Male
Marital Status:   Single
Do you want to change the age? (y or n) :y
What is the new age? :25
Do you want to change marital status? (y or n) :y
What is the new marital status? :Maried

Comment: Edit your question. I can't do anything if I don't know what you are doing...

Comment: Thanks Ben, only used site twice.  wasn't sure how to edit it.

Comment: can you put in what the input file looks like cause it's extremely hard to tell.

Comment: Joe Smo
25
Male
Maried

Comment: Hi Ray, What I can make out from your query is that you are not able to maintain space between the values of name,age etc. when writing to the file.Is it the problem?

Comment: @RayKeown: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43796267/edit) to include an example of your input along with the expected output. Without that we are really guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, because you haven't shown us your input data. But I think you're saying that your input file looks like this:

```
Joe Smo
45
Male
Single
```

And, after running your program, you end up with this:

```
Joe Smo45MaleSingle
```

When you read the file, you use the `chomp => 1` option to `read_file()`. That removes newlines from the end of the lines in the file. But `write_file()` doesn't have an `unchomp` option to replace the newlines.

The quickest, dirtiest, fix is to stop removing the newlines. You'll want to remove the `chomp => 1` option from `read_file()` and also stop calling `chomp()` on the new `$status` values as you read them in. You can also remove the "\n" from the lines where you are printing the original records (as they will have a newline attached).

However, I'd caution you against using File::Slurp. It has some problems with UTF8 data that are likely to burn you in the future. I'd recommend [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) (which has `slurp()` and `spew()` methods) in its place.

But, really, it looks like you're writing a database. So why not use a database?